# One time user account

Tags: database, statistics, billing

I have a billing system project where i have a user accounts database with tables that stores user debt,transactions,statistics etc.

Now besides the normal user accounts i need to have another type of account which is temporary and only required as long as user is considered using provided services until he billed and account is closed.

The first thought was to create a new user for each new service sale/use but it seem that i will end up with thousands accounts pretty soon.

The second approach would have an temporary account pool. The system would generate a new account when no free temporary account exists or assign one from the pool when required.

So basically this temporary accounts will identify an actual person and his transactions for a limited time.

Any ideas for the best practices in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want to have a new account for each person simply so that you have a paper trail.  I'm assuming there is going to be some kind of charge against this account.  What happens when the charge is contested and you've deleted the information about the user?  You will, at the very least, need to archive these records some place.

However, if you insist on having a temporary account, you could us a "real" account record and mark it as temporary and then run a cleanup routine periodically that deletes temporary accounts that are no longer in use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The temporary users will be actual users in the database. I will have an inherited table for them linked to the base user table. 
So with that being said all transactions will be kept and they will not ever be deleted just as for normal users.
What can be made is a periodical merge of transactions to one temporary account but even that is not required.

From statistics standpoint i don't require to know for what specific temporary user transaction was made for since i perceive them as one logical guest user.

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: If you really can just throw them away then a period delete of expired records would be my first choice.